# В чем моя ошибка при работе с объектами?

Tags: javascript

Когда вызываю объект, то значения не выводятся. Может синтаксическая ошибка?

Но если в объекте оставить 1 ключ, то значение вызывается. Не могу разобраться:(

Код: https://jsfiddle.net/75xqd1xg

```
const input = document.querySelector('input[name=inputData]');
const getdefaultInputClass = document.querySelector('input[name=inputData]').getAttribute('class');
const attr = {
    setdefaultInputClass: document.querySelector('input[name=inputData]').setAttribute('class', getdefaultInputClass),
    setWarnInputClass: document.querySelector('input[name=inputData]').setAttribute('class', 'bgred'),
    setWarnOutputClass: document.querySelector('#noticeForUser').setAttribute('class', 'bgred'),
    removeInputClass: document.querySelector('input[name=inputData]').removeAttribute('class'),
    removeOutputClass: document.querySelector('#noticeForUser').removeAttribute('class')
};
const fninput = () => {
    const userdata = {
        outputValue: document.querySelector('#noticeForUser').innerHTML = Math.ceil(input.value / 0.97),
        nan: document.querySelector('#noticeForUser').innerHTML = 'Введите цифры',
        enterValue: document.querySelector('#noticeForUser').innerHTML = 'Введите значение',
        zero: document.querySelector('#noticeForUser').innerHTML = 'Введите значение больше нуля',
        empty: document.querySelector('#noticeForUser').innerHTML = ''
    };
    if (input.value >= 1) {
        userdata.outputValue, attr.removeInputClass, attr.removeOutputClass, attr.setdefaultInputClass
    } else if (isNaN(input.value)) {
        return userdata.nan, attr.setWarnInputClass, attr.setWarnOutputClass
    } else if (input.value === '') {
        return userdata.enterValue, attr.removeInputClass, attr.removeOutputClass, attr.setdefaultInputClass
    } else if (input.value <= 0) {
        return userdata.zero, attr.setWarnInputClass, attr.setWarnOutputClass
    } else {
        return userdata.empty, attr.removeInputClass, attr.removeOutputClass, attr.setdefaultInputClass
    }
};
```

Comment: в коде вопроса нет "вывода значений" - вот они и не выводятся )

Comment: `return userdata.nan, attr.setWarnInputClass, attr.setWarnOutputClass`, `empty: document.querySelector('#noticeForUser').innerHTML = ''` - что это вообще такое? Может, почитать какую-нибудь книжку про javascript? Любую.

Comment: То есть вот этот код не является выводом?

`if (input.value >= 1) {
  return userdata.outputValue, attr.removeInputClass, attr.removeOutputClass, attr.setdefaultInputClass
 }`

Comment: Нет, не является.

Comment: а можете привести пример какой-то части рабочего кода на основании моего, пожалуйста?